# create a record when insert

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, listener

How can i add a user into the Wallet Table when a user is been created in the User table am plaining on using a event listen on the User table but its seems not working at all.

```
def User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    sponsor_referral_id = db.Column(db.String)


def Wallet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    wallet_1 = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.0)
    wallet_2 = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.0)
```

I tried this:

```
@event.listens_for(User, "after_insert")
def create_wallet(mapper, connection, target):
    target.session.add(Wallet(username=target.username))
```

Which produced nothing when a user i been added into the User table.

I Need help on how to work on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong ... But results may not be consistent when you using `after_insert` + `session.add()`. I think in you case better to use `after_flush`. Because `flush()` passes a series of operations (*insert*, *update*, *delete*) in one transaction. So you can add a new operation after `flush` but before `commit`:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import event


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://...blablalba...'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True  # let's check queries
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    sponsor_referral_id = db.Column(db.String)


class Wallet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    wallet_1 = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.0)
    wallet_2 = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.0)


@event.listens_for(db.session, 'after_flush')
def example(session, instance):
    # save new Wallet record if new User
    for rec in session.new:
        if isinstance(rec, User):
            session.add(Wallet(username=rec.username))


@app.route('/')
def test():
    # create a user and check for updates
    db.session.add(User(username='test', sponsor_referral_id='test'))
    db.session.commit()
    user1 = User.query.first()
    user1.username = 'new name'
    db.session.commit()

    # create one more user
    db.session.add(User(username='test2', sponsor_referral_id='test2'))
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'wallets': len(Wallet.query.all()), 'users': len(User.query.all())})


db.create_all()
```

Run server, open `http://localhost:5000/` and let's look at logs:

```
2021-07-16 17:48:33,992 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-07-16 17:48:33,994 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO "user" (username, sponsor_referral_id) VALUES (%(username)s, %(sponsor_referral_id)s) RETURNING "user".id
2021-07-16 17:48:33,994 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00023s] {'username': 'test', 'sponsor_referral_id': 'test'}
2021-07-16 17:48:33,997 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO wallet (username, wallet_1, wallet_2) VALUES (%(username)s, %(wallet_1)s, %(wallet_2)s) RETURNING wallet.id
2021-07-16 17:48:33,998 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00030s] {'username': 'test', 'wallet_1': 0.0, 'wallet_2': 0.0}
2021-07-16 17:48:33,999 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT


2021-07-16 17:48:34,004 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-07-16 17:48:34,006 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".username AS user_username, "user".sponsor_referral_id AS user_sponsor_referral_id 
FROM "user" 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s
2021-07-16 17:48:34,007 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00026s] {'param_1': 1}
2021-07-16 17:48:34,010 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine UPDATE "user" SET username=%(username)s WHERE "user".id = %(user_id)s
2021-07-16 17:48:34,010 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00020s] {'username': 'new name', 'user_id': 1}
2021-07-16 17:48:34,010 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT


2021-07-16 17:48:34,012 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-07-16 17:48:34,012 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO "user" (username, sponsor_referral_id) VALUES (%(username)s, %(sponsor_referral_id)s) RETURNING "user".id
2021-07-16 17:48:34,013 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.01892s ago] {'username': 'test2', 'sponsor_referral_id': 'test2'}
2021-07-16 17:48:34,014 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO wallet (username, wallet_1, wallet_2) VALUES (%(username)s, %(wallet_1)s, %(wallet_2)s) RETURNING wallet.id
2021-07-16 17:48:34,014 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.01685s ago] {'username': 'test2', 'wallet_1': 0.0, 'wallet_2': 0.0}
2021-07-16 17:48:34,015 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

Looks like what you need.

Comment: i really appreciate you a lot for saving my life, but please how can i place this listener on a Colum in the Wallet table, or rather how can i place it on a column to detect if the column was been updated. i also want to work with that as well. Thanks @Danila Ganchar

Comment: @CAP.tech could you add more more details? do you mean `User.username` **on_update listener**?

Comment: yes boss, i want to apply this listener to track if the column have been modified or change, and then do stuff like: instead of get 'rec.username', it will be 'rec.sponsor_referral_id' and then do some little trick with the sponsor_referral_id: t=Wallet.query.get(rec.sponsor_referral_id), and then add += 1 to the wallet_2 of the t. Thanks @Danila Ganchar

Comment: @CAP.tech ok. But why you don't want to use [relations](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html) or db trigger?